# Format DateTime.Now to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I want to convert the DateTime.Now to the format of `yyyy-mm-dd` since that is the only format that i can use in my query that i want to include.
The default `format` of `DateTime.Now` looks like `5/1/2008 6:32:06 PM`.
If i want to change the format of it to `yyyyMMdd` I could use this line of code:

```
var dateString1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

But, when i try the same for this `yyyy-mm-dd` format like below:

```
var dateString2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

the result i get is wrong.
For the following lines of code:

```
var dateString1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
var dateString2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");

Console.WriteLine("yyyyMMdd " + dateString1);
Console.WriteLine("yyyy-mm-dd "+ dateString2);
```

I get the following result:

[image]

which is wrong for the second case.
What am i missing?

Comment: `mm` is minutes. What you need is `MM` as in your first format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert any date format to yyyy-MM-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257483/how-to-convert-any-date-format-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) `MM` format specifier stands for month and `mm` - for minutes.

> "mm" | The minute, from 00 through 59.
>
> "MM" | The month, from 01 through 12.

So your code should look like the following:

```
    var dateString1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    var dateString2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Console.WriteLine("yyyyMMdd " + dateString1);
    Console.WriteLine("yyyy-MM-dd "+ dateString2);
```

And you will get the desired result

Answer (score 21):

```
    var dateString1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    var dateString2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Console.WriteLine("yyyyMMdd " + dateString1);
    Console.WriteLine("yyyy-MM-dd "+ dateString2);
```

You are using "mm" instead of "MM" in your second format. mm is for minutes, MM is for month.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This solved my problem but @Mikhail explained the reason so I accepted his answer and up voted yours, too. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your miss is lower-case "m" in second format, that determine MINUTES, but you need "M" instead of "m" for MONTHS.