# Datetime String conversion c# sql output parameters

Tags: c#, sql

I have a sql procedure which is outputting the following @startdate as a datetime output. I am trying to get these values into my C# aspx.cs code.

C# Output parameters

```
 cmd5.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 100, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 0, 10, "startdate", DataRowVersion.Default, null));
```

I have a public variable called startdate and trying to assign the above output parameter to the variable as seen below:

```
startdate = DateTime.Parse(cmd5.Parameters["@startdate"].Value.ToString()); //output is {01/12/2017 00:00:00} (correct date coming from sql, wrong format)
```

I need to parse this variable into another procedure from the front end. This procedure expects nvarchar(35) in sql format: yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss

How do i parse the above startdate global variable to the sql format in nvarchar(35) from here?

Comment: `DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd5.Parameters["@startdate"].Value);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - output is still {01/12/2017 00:00:00}

Comment: `DateTime.ToString`? See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings . Your `startdate` is a `DateTime` (which is correct) and it does not have a format associated with it (which is also correct). If your sproc foolishly expects a string instead of using a `DATETIME` parameter, you'll need to convert it explicitly.

Comment: this smells like a problem that should be solved by making the stored procedures use `datetime` throughout, rather than using `nvarchar(35)`; is it even remotely possible to get them to change that? because that's just bad design

Comment: I have changed it to use datetime. Regardless the format of the datetime on C# is not the same as how sql expects it

Comment: 01/12/2017 00:00:00 (this is how the variable outputs)

Comment: "the format of the datetime on C# is not the same as how sql expects it" @RA19 `datetime` (SQL) and `DateTime` (.NET) **do not have a format** - they are numbers, not strings; if you talk in `datetime` and `DateTime`: it will all work correctly. If you talk in strings: it won't

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Please include the C# source code, the stored proc source code, and the `CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format DateTime.Now to yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823758/format-datetime-now-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: I have changed the procedure to expect a datetime in all. However doesnt make sense i get the following error : The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: cmd5.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 100, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 0, 10, "startdate", DataRowVersion.Default, null));

Comment: Managed to figure it out using below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with 
`DateTime.TryParseExact(`

In `TryParseExact` method you need to pass a string and expected format.

you can find more samples and description here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I am not wanting to parse it as a string anymore as seen in above comments. I want to send it as a datetime to the procedure but i get the following The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.